# How do I kill a forkbomb process?

Tags: linux, shell

I started forkbomb from normal user account say - "user1"
I'm running a script which says

```
killall -u user1
```

But it didn't fix the situation.

Comment: Is resetting the power an option?

Comment: is there any other option?  Though reboot solves this issue. But it's not permanent solution.thanks for answer

Comment: Try `kill -9 -1`. I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810040/2541267)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

reboot the computer

if you can't, you could try:

```
killall -STOP -u user1
killall -KILL -u user1
```

If by "permanent solution", you mean preventing this happening again, well you can't really, but you can simply reduce the `ulimit` for the problem users and ignore them.

Comment: thanks setting ulimit is the permanent solution to prevent it.
But killall -KILL also worked for me.thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
while true; do killall -u user1; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Colin's answer, but I would wrap the -STOP into a script and nice --20 to ensure that the kill script gets more cpu than the 1000s bombs running.

`echo "while [ 1 ]; do killall -STOP bombprocess ; done" > killscript.sh`

or

`echo "while [ 1 ]; do killall -STOP -u userrunningthebomb ; done" > killscript.sh`

then

`nice --20 ./killscript.sh`

and then, after all of them stop

`killall -KILL bombprocess` (You should be already able to use ps again at this point)